# Using replaceWith() method to target by ID and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my jquery code works like this: when one of the default icons is clicked on and an image is loaded, it replaces that default icon that was clicked on. (There are 2 default icons with hidden file inputs). I was able to get this working by targeting the default icon's parent's classname, `.border`, but for some reason, I cannot target by the parent's ID name + [integer variable] - `#bd1` or `#bd2`. Can you please help me get my code to work so I'm able to target by ID name + [integer variable]?

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to accomplish, as the template you are replacing in is missing the id attribute, and the line you commented out will always replace the first .border it founds

Comment: @AndreaFacchini Well you pointed out something I totally overlooked - that the replaced template was missing the ID, thank you. So what I want achieved is that once `#bd1` or `#bd2` is clicked on, whichever one was clicked on will be replaced with the template containing the exact same html. I still cannot get this to work at the moment.

Comment: @AndreaFacchini Also, you were able to understand the error/issue. The commented out line only replaces the first `.border` element, but what I want achieved is that only the specific *bd ID* that was *clicked on* should get replaced. It's that one thing that I don't know how to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code in jsfiddle, it looks like there are two separate issues going on here:

**Issue #1: Event Propagation**

There is an event bubbling issue with your click events (unrelated to your jquery selectors).

When you click on the parent `.border`, it triggers a click on the child `.imginp`. When you trigger a click on the child element, the event listener on the parent is triggered again. This creates an infinite loop where the click event listener on the parent triggers a click on the child which triggers the parent click event listener etc... This results in `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Is this the behavior you are seeing as well in your console?

This happens because of [event bubbling in Javascript](https://kamranahmed.info/blog/2014/08/18/event-bubbling-and-how-can-it-be-prevented/). First, the click on the `.imginp` is handled by that element, then by it's parent, then by it's grandparent and so on and so forth, until it gets to the `window` element. That means, that even though the target was the `.imginp` element, a click also happens on the `.border` elements. This is what gets the code into a loop state.

You can fix it by adding a listener on the child to stop the propagation of the event to the parent:

```
$('#inp'+a).click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Issue #2: Variable Scope**

This IS related to your jquery selectors. Specifically, your use of selectors using the loop variable `a` and the execution of the the `change` event callback.

A quick example of what is happening here.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, 100)
}
```

When you see this code at first glance, you might expect for it to log `0, 1,2`. Instead, it will log `3,3,3`. This is because by the time the timeout function runs, the value of `a` is 3.

This is exactly what is happening at this line in your code `$('#bd'+a).replaceWith(template);`. If you add a `console.log` here you can see this behavior in action. At the time of execution, the value of `a` here is not 1 or 2, but 3. This is because it is using the most recent value of `a`, not the value of `a` at the time the function was defined.

This has to do with the behavior of the event loop in javascript. When the `change` callback is executed and `#bd + a` is evalutated, the value of `a` is 3. We can fix this using a [closure](https://blog.angular-university.io/really-understanding-javascript-closures/) which would enable us to 'close' over the value of `a` with what it was at the time of the function declaration in the loop. This is a pretty good example of how a closure is used with [async functions defined in for loops](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/).

ES6 provides another option for how to prevent this issue. The keyword `let` enables us to have block level scoping of our variables. This means, that we can use it in our for loop to define `a` for each loop with block level scoping to the loop and the `change` callback defined in it. You would use it like so:

```
for (let a = 1; a < 3; a++) {...}
```

This has the added benefit of also fixing the way your for loop is currently written: with `a` as a global variable. This is typically not desirable and can have unintended consequences if you define or use a variable `a` elsewhere in your code.

**Final Code:**

```
for (let a = 1; a < 3; a++) {
    $("#bd"+a).click(function(e) {
        $(this).children(".imginp").click()
    });
    $('#inp'+a).click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#inp'+a).on('change', function(e){
      var files = e.target.files;
      $.each(files, function(i, file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(e){
            template = 
            '<div class="border">'+
                '<input id="inp'+a+'" class="imginp" type="file" hidden>'+
            '<img class="blah" src="'+e.target.result+'">'+
            '</div>';
            $('#bd'+a).replaceWith(template);
        };
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you've exactly identified the problems with my code! So many concepts here I was never aware of. I've had the issue with the for loop elsewhere in my code with the last number repeating. I never understood it before, so thanks for further explaining that here with `let`. You also explained event bubbling in a way that makes more sense to me now. Thanks, thanks greatly!!